# How do I implement something like an HTTPListener on the server side of a Blazor Webassembly app?

Tags: multithreading, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have figured out that I can send information from the server part of a Blazor Webassembly app to the client via SignalR. However, I now have the issue that my server needs to be able to react to information coming from another application. I have a console application that is supposed to send information to my server, for example via an HTTPListener. This would be trivial if I could open up a Thread in my server, but apparenty WebAssembly does not allow that. I feel like I must clearly be missing something here, as this feels like a common issue. How do I get information pushed into the server part of my app through the net?

Regards,
MRB

Comment: The Server part of a Blazor Wasm Hosted app already _is_ an HttpListener. You can just add an endpoint for your Console app to talk to.

Comment: ... wow, that is actually really obvious, isn't it? Thank you, that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Henk Holterman solved this one for me. I was thinking way too complicated, just made another HTTPost method to get called from anywhere and it did the trick.